# Explain DOM 11 error in the initialization of XMLHttpRequest with JSON -headers

Tags: javascript, json, dom, xmlhttprequest

I am getting this error as part of this larger puzzle [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11083010/164148).

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );

//Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11
```

**For further research**

> 1. O'Reilly's book "Definite Guide to Javascript 6th Edition" on page 491 in chapter 18 "Scripted HTTP" discussed XMLHttpRequest, please,
>      note that it is not only about HTTP or XML (historical relics).
> 2. Mozilla's dev entry about XMLHttpREquest [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: possible duplicate of [INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11 (WebKit)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488698/invalid-state-err-dom-exception-11-webkit)

Comment: Have you tried searching Stack Overflow for "DOM 11"? There already exist a bunch of threads addressing this issue.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: That's not a good duplicate. INVALID_STATE_ERR/11 is used for *so many things*...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to `open()` the `XMLHttpRequest` before you can set request headers. Just move that line to after you call `open()`:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open( 'POST', 'example.php', true );
xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );
```

Comment: Suppose I just run my code in Browser console, what should the `"example.php"` be in that case? The Mozilla Dev -site has some monster `"url += ((/\?/).test(url) ? "&" : "?") + (new Date()).getTime()"` but probably not something here? (sorry this may be a dump question, still learning/reading stuff...)

Comment: @hhh: Whatever page it is you want to request - but it has to be in the same domain name, or you'll get an exception.

Comment: There is one problem, there is no page. My purpose in the other question is to add content to the db in the address `http://127.0.0.1:5984/test`, couchDB can be accessed like that.

Comment: @hhh: If there's no page, where is your JavaScript running? Just any old website that you happen to have a Developer Tools window open on?

Comment: Yes, on any page really `CTRL+SHIFT J` and copy-pasting the code on any page, even the loading Chromium -page having only the windows about historical browsing -- its source is `view-source:chrome://newtab/`. Any placeholder for some generic solution?

Comment: @hhh: If CouchDB is set up for easy JavaScript access (I don't know), just try putting in that URL. Otherwise, you'll need to send some extra headers - read up on CORS. Or, if this is just for yourself, you can start up instances of Chrome[ium] with the flag `--disable-web-security` - but don't browse anywhere else with that.