# Google Chrome Extension, dom exception as XMLHttpReqest.open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools

I'm developing a chrome extension, tried to post a page's title & content to a server, with following code in the popup.js, but found req.open throws out DOMException ( invalide state as code 11).
And, I already add permission as     `"permissions": [  "tabs",  "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]`, it still dosent work. How can I fix this?

```
function addBookmark()
{
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.open("POST", "remote_sever_url/quote/new", true);

var params  = "title=" + document.getElementById("title").value + 
            "&text=" + document.getElementById("text").value +
            "&url=" + document.getElementById("url").value + 
            "&tags=" + document.getElementById("tags").value;

req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
req.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

req.send(params);
```

Comment: Maybe you should encode your params with `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: Your code, as posted, works fine for me. Are you sure that the error is not happening on a later line? Do you ever attempt to access the `status` or `responseText` properties of `req` outside of a `onreadystatechange` or `onload` handler? See the second answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488698/invalid-state-err-dom-exception-11-webkit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error on sending POST request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248717/error-on-sending-post-request)