# Chrome/WebKit XHR File Upload

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have searched relentlessly but just can't figure this one out.  Why will this XHR connection work **perfectly fine in Firefox** but breaks in Chrome?  I'm using this in conjunction with AngularJS, by the way.

```js
$scope.upload = function(project, file) {
                var formData = new FormData();  //Not really sure why we have to use FormData().  Oh yeah, browsers suck.
                formData.append('', file.file); //The real file object is stored in this file container

                file.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                file.xhr.open('PUT', '/api/projects/'+project._id+'/files', true);

                //Progress event listener
                file.xhr.upload.onprogress = function(event) {
                    if(event.lengthComputable) {
                        file.uploadPercent = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);
                    }
                };

                //Upload complete listener
                file.xhr.upload.onload = function(event) {
                    file.uploaded = true;
                };

                //Every time the status changes
                file.xhr.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
                    if(event.target.readyState == 4) {
                        //The file has been added, so tag the ID onto the file object
                        console.log(event.target.responseText);
                        file._id = JSON.parse(event.target.responseText)._id;
                    } else {
                        return;
                    }
                };

                file.xhr.send(formData);
            };
```

In Firefox, the file is sent just fine to my server, and the `responseText` is returned exactly like I'd expect.  However, in Chrome, I get this error:  `Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11
Error: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.`, which would be more helpful if it told me exactly what object was attempted to be used.  I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5319647/371273) that I should try to set `async` to false and use `onreadystatechange`, but I'm not sure how that helps, since I'm already using `onreadystatechange`.

Comment: Did you read this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488698/invalid-state-err-dom-exception-11-webkit ?

Comment: (ಠ_ಠ) I referenced that post in my question, specifically the answer by Dave Lampert.  When I set `async` to false in my `xhr.open()` call, the error is gone but Chrome still doesn't even send the file to the server.

Comment: If you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) I'm happy to take a look. Here's a simplified version of [my upload service](http://jsfiddle.net/5CYDV/). Maybe that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Bug from 2009: XMLHttpRequest doesn't work while submitting a form - https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23933