# Uncaught Error: InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11 with AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm running a simple AJAX request:

```
function makePages(num) {

    var conn = new XMLHttpRequest();

    conn.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (conn.status === 200 && conn.readyState === 4) {  //error here
            $('#oldPost').before(conn.responseText);
        }
        else{
            return
        }
    }

    conn.open('GET','includes/feedExtra.php?num=' + num);
    conn.send();
}
```

The code runs correctly and the PHP returns the correct content. However, there is an error in Chrome's console:

> Uncaught Error: InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11

it points to this line:

> if (conn.status === 200 && conn.readyState === 4) {

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error:

```
Uncaught Error: InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11
```

Means you are asking for status in the wrong state.  conn.status is not available during readyState of 0 or 1.

Your problem is you are using conn.status when the readyState is 0 and 1.

You need to add code to make sure conn.status is not queried in the inappropriate states, like this:

```
if(conn.readyState === 4 && conn.status === 200){
```

Then your code will only query conn.status at the appropriate time.

Ref:

[why does this piece of js throw a DOM Exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622985/why-does-this-piece-of-js-throw-a-dom-exception)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
conn.open('GET','includes/feedExtra.php?num=' + num, false);
```

`false` makes the request synchronous, `true` / default is asynchronous.

In your case, it's defaulting to `true`, which means the properties in your conditional `(conn.status === 200 && conn.readyState === 4)` aren't available **yet**. They will be until after the call.

Hopefully that helps you some.

Also, checkout this discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488698/invalid-state-err-dom-exception-11-webkit).

Comment: Wow thanks for the link I couldn't find anything like that, haha. It turns out that you were right, I needed to make sure that the 'readyState == 4' before I did anything so I just wrapped a huge if function around everything and the error is gone! :D