# why does this piece of js throw a DOM Exception?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I can't figure out why this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bevacqua/kDtQb/) throws

> Uncaught Error: InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11

```
function url(){
 return '/echo/js/?js=' + 5 + Math.floor(Math.random()*900);
}

function poll(done){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.status === 200 && xhr.readyState === 4){
            var foo = xhr.responseText;
            done(parseInt(foo));
        }
    };
    xhr.open('get',url(),false);
    xhr.send(null);
}

var button = document.querySelector('#poller');
var price = document.querySelector('#price');

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    poll(function(data){
        price.innerText = data;
    });
},false);
```

Comment: Your fiddle works well for me. On which line do you get that error message?

Comment: after clicking the button

Comment: @EricLeschinski Not true, `readyState` is immediately available...it's a property of `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: And why are you sending a synchronous request (`false` third parameter) yet using the `onreadystatechange` method?

Comment: I was just testing out different setups

Comment: If you look at the MDN docs, it says not to use `onreadystatechange` with synchronous requests... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#Properties

Comment: I didn't even notice the `false` *shudder*

Comment: Either way, don't use `onreadystatechange` with synchronous requests. Immediately after the `xhr.send(null);` line, just check `xhr.status` and `xhr.readyState` like you want. Also, I wouldn't use synchronous requests unless you have a good reason and understand its use. With asynchronous requests, you have it setup correctly (except for the problem you're having)

Comment: I wouldn't, ever. I'm just testing out interview question style, coding by hand

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the status not available when the readyState is 0/1

You need to reverse the order in your if.

```
if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200){
```

The spec says it should return zero ["If the state is UNSENT or OPENED, return 0 and terminate these steps."](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-status-attribute), but for some reason some browsers do this "Throws an "InvalidStateError" exception if the state is not OPENED or if the send() flag is set." which is what [setRequestHeader](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader%28%29-method) does. Also your code is weird that you would use it with a synchronous request.

So the issue here is the browser is not returning zero like the spec says so. Changing the order in the if statement prevents the browser from reaching that point since the first check fails.

And the [bug on WebKit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45994)

Comment: Good catch. What I don't understand is why an exception is thrown because wouldn't `xhr.status` just be `undefined` (or whatever) and just not be equal to `200`? I would think it would just fail the condition, not bomb the code

Comment: but if you open the connection before you set ready state handler this error does not occur.

Comment: Really? Shouldn't it just be `0` (as in Opera) or `undefined` then instead of throwing an exception?

Comment: I wonder if the real problem is because `onreadystatechange` is being used with a synchronous request...

Comment: no, it wasn't, that didn't seem to change anything, the ordering of checking readyState though fixes it. it's weird that status throws when accessed (`if readyState === 0`), though..

Comment: The spec says it should return zero ["If the state is UNSENT or OPENED, return 0 and terminate these steps."](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-status-attribute), but for some reason some browsers do this "Throws an "InvalidStateError" exception if the state is not OPENED or if the send() flag is set." which is what [setRequestHeader](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader()-method) does. Also your code is weird that you would use it with a synchronous request.

Comment: @epascarello: Put that in the answer and you'll get another upvote :-)

Comment: I just added the webkit bug to the question which was reported in 2010. :)